# The application stopped unexpectedly please try again later-Force close

Tags: java, android

Now just trying to create an android application to login using eclipse.
But when i run the code getting the above mentioned error.Whil lookin at logcat it shows the error in line 36 but no idea for me to how to recover it,

here is my code:

```
package com.example.login;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText un,pw;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));

                String response = null;
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("<target page url>", postParameters);
                    String res=response.toString();
                    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    if(res.equals("1"))
                        error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                    else
                        error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    un.setText(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is my logcat:

```
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login/com.example.login.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.example.login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
04-04 11:14:26.657: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 11 more
```

Its appreciable if i get an solution to this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `un` is null forget to initialize before calling getText()

Comment: @user3312675, Whether any of the below answer is worked or not?

Comment: i tried those but nothing works.:(

Answer (score 1):

add following line of code in on create

```
 un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
```

Hope this will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Declare this, you forget to initialize your Username's edit-text inside your onCreate method. You have declared pw, Ok and error but forget to declare un. So declare it like below and try.

```
un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
//...
ok.setOnClickListener(...)
```

Make sure your `activity_main` layout really contains a view with id `btn_login`. `ok` being null here is really the only explanation for the NPE in your stacktrace.

`un` is also not initialized as mentioned by others but that would only cause a NPE later, with a different stacktrace involving `onClick()` and not `onCreate()`.

Comment: my activity main contains the view for btn_login.

Comment: `ok` being null is still the reason. If you've recently reordered elements in your XML files, clean and rebuild the app. Sometimes identifiers in generated `R` and binary XML files go out of sync, and a complete rebuild helps there.

Comment: Also: consider running the code in a debugger to examine program flow and variable contents at runtime. You'll need the debugging skill eventually anyway.

Comment: ok ok thanks for your suggestion...i'll check in debugging mode.